# Homeomorphism of a mapping governed by an ode

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

A mapping or solution $g(x_0,t_f):x_0 {\rightarrow} x$ of an ode $\dot{y}=f(y,t)$ is a Homeomorphism for any constant $t_f$. I have a mapping which is also a solution for an ode, but with **continues, non-constant** $t_f$, is this mapping still a Homeomorphism?

For example given the mapping $g(x_0,t_f)=x_0e^{t_f}$. If $x_0=(1,2)$ and $t_f=\frac{x_0}{2} $ ($t_f$ is a continues function of $x_0$). Than $g(x_0,t_f):(1,2){\rightarrow} (e^\frac{1}{2},2e)$ is a maping of an open-set to an open-set i.e. a Homeomorphism.

How can I test/prove if such a mapping is a Homeomorphism when the analytic mapping is not available (because there is no explicit solution for the ode)?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague, and your last sentence does not particularly help. Can you ask a more precise question, perhaps with a precise example in mind?

Comment: In particular, are you asking a question about flows? And about the first return map of a co-dimension 1 transversal to the flow, as in the beginning of [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_map)?

Comment: Thanks @LeeMosher. Please see edited question.

Comment: For a periodic function $f(x,t+T)=f(x,t)$ you would most likely be interested in the maps to fixed time lengths using the period $T$ or a multiple of it. Is there a reason that you want to use variable lengths in that situation?

Comment: Hi @LutzL. My system is periodic in the since that it crosses the Poincare section on each cycle, this can occur at different times for different cycles. Best think of it as a first return map not as periodic mapping.

Comment: But what is the Poincaré section? It has to be some surface $p(x,t)=0$ that is transversal to the solution curves. $p(x,t)=t-T$ works, but you might be thinking more about $p(x,t)=x_1$?

Comment: The Poincare section is a surface in phase space which is transverse to the flow $p(\bar{x})=0$. The time (or independent) variable is not part of the surface definition.